# Angular 5 input output

Tags: input, output, angular5

In my application there is a toolbar in the a navigation component. This navigation component is part of the app.component along with the place for other components to show. I have a login page from where I want to transfer a variable to the app.component and then on the basis of the variable the toolbar should be changed. From login component I am transferring the variable through @output and eventemitter but in app.component I am not receiving it. The code is as follows.

app.component.ts

---

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {

  myrole = 'NoUser';

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.myrole);
  }
}
```

login.component.ts

---

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  Name: string;
  Pass: string;
  @Output() myrole = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private rout: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  OnName(event: any)
  {
    this.Name = event.target.value;
    if (this.Name === 'admin' || this.Name === 'Admin') {
      this.myrole.emit('admin');
    } else if (this.Name === 'user' || this.Name === 'User') {
      this.myrole.emit('user');
    } else {
      this.myrole.emit('NoUser');
    }
    console.log(this.myrole);
  }

  onPass(event: any)
  {
    this.Pass = event.target.value;
  }

  Submit() {

    this.rout.navigate(['*']);
  }

}
```

navi.component.ts

---

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navi',
  templateUrl: './navi.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navi.component.css']
})
export class NaviComponent implements OnInit {

@Input() myrole: string;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.myrole);
}
}
```

app.component.html

---

```
<app-navi [myrole]='myrole'></app-navi>
<br>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: Can you add a (cut down) version of your app.component.html please, to show how the login component is included in the app component?

Comment: @MarkHughes added app.component.html

Comment: The login component doesn't seem to be there... How is it included?

Comment: it is through router output. There is a link in the tool bar to load login component in routeroutlet.

Comment: Can you add the routing module to the question? My understanding is that @Output decorators only work when including the component via a template (e.g. `<app-login (myrole)="roleUpdated($event)"></app-login>`), not via routing outputs.